# Solving Recurrence Relation with Forward Substitution

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relations, induction

I've found myself quite stuck on this recurrence relation. I've been given it to solve, via forward substitution and verify using induction. I start out with

$$
T(n) = 4T(n/3)
$$

For all $n > 1$ where $n$ is some power of $3$.

I started out with forward substitution and asserted my assumption that:

$$
T(n) = 4^{\log_3(n)}
$$

At that point I asserted the induction step that I have to prove:

$$
T(3n) = 4^{\log_3(3n)} = 4^n
$$

So I started out with:
$$
T(3n) = 4T(3n/3)
$$
Then I simplified:
$$
T(3n) = 4T(n)
$$

As per my assumption, I substituted $T(n)$.

$$
T(3n) = 4 \cdot 4^{\log_3(n)}
$$

This is where I get stuck, and I was just wondering if someone could point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What was your initial value?   You need it for forward substitution, as you are observing a pattern and then proving through induction.  Let's assume T(1) = 1.

$$T(3) = 4$$

$$T(9) = 4 \cdot 4 = 4^2 = 16$$

$$T(27)  = 4 \cdot 16 = 4^3 = 64$$

So now prove that $T(3^n) = 4^n$.  Know that $T(1)=1$, assume that $T(3^n)=4^n$. Then

$$T(3^{n+1}) = 4 T(3^n) = 4 \cdot 4^n = 4^{n+1}$$

So we proved the formula by induction.

We may also solve this equation in closed form directly as follows.

Let $n=3^m$, and

$$T\left(3^m\right) = U_m$$

Then

$$U_m = 4 U_{m-1}$$

which means that

$$U_m = 4^m \, U_0$$

This is the solution for $n$ being a power of $3$.  However, we can go further.  Substituting $m =  \log_3{n}= \log{n}/\log{3}$, we get

$$T(n) = 4^{\log{n}/\log{3}}T(1)$$

or rewriting using $n = e^{\log{n}}$:

$$T(n) = T(1) n^{\log{4}/\log{3}} = T(1) n^{\log_3{4}}$$

Comment: I'm sorry dude. I'm not all too good with this topic, and when you throw in Um into the picture, you just throw me. Is there anyway you could start by using my terminology?

Comment: @ChrisCooney: I just did.